# how to charge 2 Lithium ion 18650 batteries in Series and Parallel

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, bms

i want to charge my 2 lithium ion batteries in series and parallel.
as per my knowledge
**for single cell Capacity 3350mAh** as per datasheet
charge voltage: 4.2 V DC
Charge current: 0.5C (1700mA)
cut-off current: 0.02C (68mA)

**for 2 cell in parallel** as per my understanding it will be acting as high capacity single cell of capacity 6700mAh and voltage 3.6 V DC
charge voltage: 4.2 V DC
Charge current: 0.5C (3400mA) as connecting in parallel will increase the capacity
cut-off current: 0.02C (136mA)

**for 2 cell in Series** as per my understanding it will be acting as high voltage single cell of capacity 3350mAh and voltage 7.2
charge voltage: 8.4 V DC
Charge current: 0.5C (1700mA) as connecting in parallel will increase the capacity
cut-off current: 0.02C (68mA)
individual cell voltage should be monitored for safety

please check this and guide me if i misunderstood this

Comment: Your calculations are correct.

Comment: You can charge in series **Or** in parallel ie not both at the same time.